# why did the command udhcpc fail to set timeout on linux?

Tags: networking

Now,I want to get an ip in 5 seconds by the command ：

```
udhcpc  -i eth2 -R -A 5
```

I wish if after 5 seconds, the above command can't get an ip, this command can exist auto, but I found the option "-A 5" is useless. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're running Ubuntu? Either way, there may be some conflicting flags in your command.

The `-A` flag controls how long `udhcpc` should wait for an IP lease before sending another request. `-A 5` means that it will send a request every 5 seconds until it receives one.

The `-R` flag will release an IP once `udhcpc` exits, which may or may not nullify what it is you're trying to do with `-A`.

If your goal is to obtain a new IP lease on `eth2` with the command giving up after 5 seconds, perhaps this will do what you're looking for:

```
udhcpc -i eth2 -t 1 -n
```

`-t` will send up to `N` discover packets. In this case, it's just `1`.

`-n` will exit if the lease is not obtained.